# Move question from Stack Overflow to Super User without moderator approval

Tags: support, specific-question, scope, migration

Can I move one of my question from Stack Overflow to super user, I have created a question in Stack Overflow When I try to delete the post it says you may be blocked from further asking question.

Since I am the owner of the question, I feel whoever asks question should get option to move to different forum.

Below is Link: [Port scan fails when firewall is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50033944/port-scan-fails-when-firewall-is-enabled/50033980?noredirect=1#comment87087278_50033980)

Comment: Your question has an answer. It is not a good practice to delete questions with answers.

Comment: Somebody put some effort into answering your question, and now you want to delete the whole thing. Not fair, isn't it?

Comment: i dont want to delete the post, feel it should be in the superuser

Comment: You can flag for migration, if you are really sure that this q&a would be on-topic there. Or even flag it for moderation attention. But you can't migrate it on your own.

Comment: I doubt that question is on-topic on SU, despite users claiming firewall questions shouldn't be asked on SO.

Comment: If in doubt, don't migrate.  It it the OP's responsibility to post on the most suitable site where its question/s is on-topic.

Comment: thanks guys, i just flagged that post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That question was about getting your code to work, so I disagree that it's off-topic for Stack Overflow. You have a partial answer now that should lead you to ask a follow-up question about firewalls on Super User. Since that's a separate question, I don't see any reason to delete the existing one. You might want to link to it for reference when you ask your next question.